# <div type="text"> Why specify type?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I was reading the jQuery UI API for datepicker. The example code has something new to me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">

<div type="text" id="datepicker"></div>  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<"type"???

</body>
</html>
```

I tried it without *type="text"* and it doesn't work anymore. Why is that?

I'm new to HTML and I have never seen assigning a type to div. Searching on the Internet, I couldn't find any example for *div*. All I see is *type* for other elements like *style* and *script*. I couldn't find any relevant questions at stackoverflow either.

Why would we need to assign a type to div?

Ref: download jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.zip. It's in the "development-bundle\docs\datepicker.html#demo" (the official demo code in the offline documentation for jquery-ui datepicker)

Edit: it turned out to be a bug in the documentation of jquery datepicker demo code. I reported it and they fixed it within few hours so this question doesn't apply to the latest version of the document.

Comment: Where does it say that in the documentation?

Comment: Did you look through the jquery or css files to know how it is that it's being used?? Probably it's only intended to be used by the scripts. Open the script (.js) files and look for [type="text"] to see where in the file it is being used (or look for attr('text' without the closing parenthesis. You may also want to see the .css file to find something similar

Comment: Simple misunderstanding of the datepicker - you need to apply it to textbox meaning **input** of type text, not `<div>` element. When you do that, the date chosen by the user will be inserted to that textbox.

Comment: This is where I found it: Ref: download jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.zip. It's in the "development-bundle\docs\datepicker.html#demo" (the official demo code in the offline documentation for jquery-ui datepicker)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, i couldn't find any reference to the fact that you had to use a div in the documentation, what i'm sure of is that you must use an input of type text. Taken from the [demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/):

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
    </script>



<div class="demo">

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

</div><!-- End demo -->
```

Moreover: what do you need a datepicker for if you have no input field?

Comment: That makes sense. Apparently it's a mistype in the documentation of jquery-ui. I changed the div to input and it works the way it should: an edit box is shown and when you click it, the datepicker pops up. I filed a ticket to solve this issue: http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7527

Answer (score 3):

`<div>` doesn't have attribute type. It isn't neessary and you should not use it